# Adding Event Listeners to an Array that Execute Drag and Drop Functions in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

This is my first real programming endeavor and this is the last thing holding my little project back from being a success.

My goal with this code is to add event listeners to an array of Movie Clips that will drag and drop them on the stage.

Here is the code:

```
var itemBank:Array = new Array(d1_anim.drawer1.test01.movieClip_1, d1_anim.drawer1.test01.movieClip_2);

for(var i:int = 0; i < itemBank.length; i++) {
    itemBank[i].buttonMode = true;
    itemBank[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    itemBank[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropOff);
    trace("pickUp added to " + itemBank[i]);
}

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    trace("Draging " + event.target);
}
```

Right now the MC does not drag and the trace statement says:

> pickUp added to [object MovieClip]

EDIT:
Here is my fla, I give up. I don't know why it wont work. Please help.
[Download it here](Edit: removed download link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code has been tested and works fine. The error must be somewhere else.

If you want the test code i used you can download the source here: [Drag & Drop Source File](http://www.4shared.com/file/XlhkDPzp/Drag_Drop_Demo.html) (Same code as yours, this is just a proof that it works).

---

**EDIT:** Here are the changes that i made to your code to make it work. Read the comments for better understanding. I also changed the registration point of the `d1_anim.drawer1.test01.hair1` movie clip to center instead of top-left, this is needed to make it work.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.reintroducing.ui.SliderUI; // Always have imports at top. It's a good practice.

var itemBank:Array = new Array(d1_anim.drawer1.test01.hair1);

for(var i:int = 0; i < itemBank.length; i++) {
    itemBank[i].buttonMode = true;
    itemBank[i].mouseChildren = false;// Added this line. For explanation go to: http://ryanbosinger.com/blog/2008/actionscript-3-eventtarget-returns-children-of-movieclip/
    itemBank[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    itemBank[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropOff);
    trace("pickUp added to " + itemBank[i]);
}

function pickUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(true);
    trace("Draging " + e.currentTarget);
}
function dropOff(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // --- Change 'this' to 'e.currentTarget' --- \\
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    e.currentTarget.x = mouseX;
    e.currentTarget.y = mouseY;
    e.currentTarget.width = 200;
    // --- Putting the target in a temporary variable made an error dissapear. --- \\
    // --- I don't really know why and i don't really care either --- \\
    var tempMC = e.currentTarget;
    this.stage.addChild(tempMC);
    d1_anim.visible = false;
}
```

[And here is a link to the working .fla](http://www.4shared.com/file/nJETzzso/Drag_Drop_Demo_2.html)

Comment: Wow, interesting. I'm not sure if thats great news or bad news though haha. Checking it out

Comment: Okay, the only difference is that my MC are on a certain frame of one of the parent MCs. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Zrean Tofiq
Here is my fla, I give up. I don't know why it wont work. Please help.
[Download it here](https://www.yousendit.com/download/eURBN3RRNDQ5eFZjR0E9PQ)

Comment: @jonshariat There you go. It is all working fine now. Just download the .fla from the link at the bottom and use it. If you need any further explanation of what i did just drop me a comment and i'll answer you the best i can.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been tearing my hair out for the past two days trying to get this to work. I really appreciate your help and quick replies. You are a life saver!

Comment: So, P.S. it still didnt work until I commented out the slideUI. I'm going to have to figure out why later.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry i can't help u with the sliderUI thingy. I don't have the class and i don't know about it, so it will be hard to troubleshoot it. A tip would be to post a new question concerning that matter.

Comment: @jonshariat Also, would you like me to remove the download link? Or is it ok if it stays there for others having similar problems?